# Cannot resolve symbol RetryHttpInitializerWrapper - Google IOT

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, iot

I am trying to create a device in my IOT platform on google cloud. When following instructions and example i get "Cannot resolve symbol "RetryHttpInitializerWrapper". I have checked if I have the last Maven version, tested with both JDK 11 and 8, and searched around for anyone with the same problem.

Link to google cloud guide: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#iot-core-create-rs256-java

Link to google Github: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/api-client/manager/src/main/java/com/example/cloud/iot/examples/DeviceRegistryExample.java

In my code the only problem lies in line 57 where I try to create a new "RetryHttpInitializerWrapper" under the method "createDevice"

Here is my method:

```
public static void createDevice(
        String projectId, String cloudRegion, String registryName, String deviceId)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    // [START create_device]
    GoogleCredential credential =
            GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(CloudIotScopes.all());
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpRequestInitializer init = new RetryHttpInitializerWrapper(credential);
    final CloudIot service =
            new CloudIot.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), jsonFactory, init)
                    .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                    .build();

    final String registryPath =
            String.format(
                    "projects/%s/locations/%s/registries/%s", projectId, cloudRegion, registryName);

    List<Device> devices =
            service
                    .projects()
                    .locations()
                    .registries()
                    .devices()
                    .list(registryPath)
                    .setFieldMask("config,gatewayConfig")
                    .execute()
                    .getDevices();

    if (devices != null) {
        System.out.println("Found " + devices.size() + " devices");
        for (Device d : devices) {
            if ((d.getId() != null && d.getId().equals(deviceId))
                    || (d.getName() != null && d.getName().equals(deviceId))) {
                System.out.println("Device exists, skipping.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my imports:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.cloudiot.v1.CloudIot;
import com.google.api.services.cloudiot.v1.CloudIotScopes;
import com.google.api.services.cloudiot.v1.model.Device;
import com.google.cloud.Role;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient;
import com.google.iam.v1.Binding;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.Topic;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.List;
```

My POM.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>no.something</groupId>
<artifactId>MQTTbridge</artifactId>
<version>11.0</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudiot</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev20181120-1.27.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like the class RetryHttpInitializerWrapper.class exists in any of the maven dependencies you have. I also looked on maven repositories for the java-docs-samples referenced in github, but doesn't seem like it's pushed there either. You can look at the sample implementation for RetryHttpInitializerWrapper that Google has on Github and potentially create your own:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/storage-transfer/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/storagetransfer/samples/RetryHttpInitializerWrapper.java